# Meaning of "constituted" as an adjective

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Norman Lewis's Word Power Made Easy, I found the following sentence:

> It is only the few who are so constituted that lack of learning becomes a nuisance.

What does "constituted" mean in this context?

Source: [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=OkToAgAAQBAJ&pg=PP49&lpg=PP49&dq=It%20is%20only%20the%20few%20who%20are%20so%20constituted%20that%20lack%20of%20learning%20becomes%20a%20nuisance.&source=bl&ots=0T_7I1ccVC&sig=YIP3pvH4g4xuh7z19UdYoghNc3Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4p7ih8r_OAhUENiYKHffkCy4Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=It%20is%20only%20the%20few%20who%20are%20so%20constituted%20that%20lack%20of%20learning%20becomes%20a%20nuisance.&f=false)

Comment: Built, constructed, have the character.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an adjective in this context; the "so constituted" is referring to the topic in the sentence before. The '**so constituted**' could be better read "**in this manner constituted**." Look at it again:

*"All normal human beings are born with a powerful urge to learn. **Almost all of them lose this urge**, even before they have reached maturity. It is only the few .....who are **so constituted** that lack of learning becomes a nuisance. This is perhaps the most insidious of human tragedies.”*

The "so constituted" is referencing those who have not lost the urge to learn, in order to make his point.

Hope this clears it up; thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It does make sense that the "so constituted" is referring to the topic in the previous sentence, but what part of speech is "constituted" in this case? Is it a passive verb as in: "The Federation was constituted in 1949"? I looked up the word "constitute" and found nothing that could mean something to be used as a reference.

Comment: I think "constituted" is an adjective modifying "the few" but makes more sense in the context of the full paragraph so that you know what "the few" is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Constituted as an adjective means long established or setup and in the following sentence “It is only the few...who are so constituted that lack of learning becomes a nuisance”, it means that very few people keep learning from childhood to adulthood and maintain their habit of learning, that is they establish themselves and as a result lack of learning annoys them.